# How to automatically cycle though an array of images?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I need to make a set of images change automatically, they're traffic lights to be precise. I am using an array with a button that makes it change, but I need to to cycle through it automatically. How would I go about doing this?

```html
<img id="light" src="N:\Computing Year 10\Year 10 CS\A452 - First Assessment\Programming\trafficlights\1red.png">

<button type="button" onclick="changeLights()">Change Lights</button> <!-- Button used to change lights-->
```

```js
var lightList = [
    "1red.png",       /* index 0 */
    "2redamber.png",  /* index 1 */
    "3green.png",     /* index 2 */
    "4amber.png"      /* index 3 */
];

var index = 0;  /* New variable called 'index' set to 0 */

function changeLights() {
    index = index + 1;     /* This assigns the changeLights buttom the function of addind 1 to the value of index, which changes the traffic light */

    if (index == lightList.length) index = 0;

    var image = document.getElementById('light');
    image.src=lightList[index];
}
```

http://pastebin.com/Bwk7E61Y

Comment: Instead of storing them in array, you can just use them as image tag with display:none and toggle their visibility in button click

Comment: Have a look at [`window.setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)

Answer (score 1):

You can call the `changeLights()` function every second by using `setInterval`. You can read about `setInterval` function [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp). You can choose the time interval of your choice for calling the function.

```
window.onload = function() {
    setInterval(function(){ 

    changeLights();

    }, 1000);
}
```